# How do I turn a 404 page into an automatic search with the info from the url?

Tags: genesis-theme-framework

All 404 implementations seem to revolve around showing related content. I think we can do one better by automatically searching for the missing post... How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done in two easy steps.

1. Upgrade your site search with a plug in, such as Relevanssi (optional).
2. Add the following code in functions.php or via Code Snippets (thx to @Howdy_McGee and Russell Jamieson for ideas!)

```
function wpse_204310() {

    global $wp_query;

    if( is_404()
        && !is_robots() 
        && !is_feed() 
        && !is_trackback()
      ) {
        $uri    = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $clean  = str_replace( "/", "%20", $uri );
        $clean2 = str_replace( "-", "%20", $clean ); 
        wp_redirect( home_url( "/?s={$clean2}" ) );
        exit();
    }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse_204310' );
```

That's it. This code will parse the url for the blog title, and pass it along to your search page. All transparent to the user. This assumes a simple permalink structure, such as domain.com/post-title

Comment: i posted a code sample. why is it now showing???

Comment: Try indentation - [Formatting Help](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)

Comment: I think the editor was thinking i was still in ordered list mode. Thx!

Comment: The indentation looks messed up - [check out formatting](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

Comment: i know! tried everything already to fix that. seems indented properly...

Comment: Oh, there's a general issue with code blocks after lists. added a comment tag to separate the two `<!-- Separate -->`

Comment: ahhh, nice trick!

Answer (score 1):

You could grab the pagename they're looking for on 404 and use [`template_redirect`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) to put that pagename into the default search:

```
function wpse_204310() {
    global $wp_query;

    if( is_404() ) {
        $slug = $wp_query->get( 'pagename' );
        wp_redirect( home_url( "/?s={$slug}" ) );
        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse_204310' );
```

The default WordPress search isn't the best and I'm not sure how the above snippet will interact with plugins that attempt to improve the default search but that's one possible solution.

Comment: seems like it should work but $slug = $wp_query->get( 'pagename' ); returns "" when page is not found (that kind of makes sense - there is no page name in that case)

Comment: @rothschild86 Even on 404 there is still a pagename, whatever the user is attempting to get to. I just tested it and it seems to work fine. For example: `http://example.com/pagename/` would return `pagename` as the slug since that's what it's *trying* to look for even if it doesn't exist. I tested it and it still works fine / as expected unless I'm missing what you're trying to achieve here. You could check if `$slug` is empty in a case I can't reproduce then run additional code for the redirect.

Comment: very strange. could not get anything here. reverted to using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; for now... Added a few more conditions that seen in other plugins: && !is_robots() 
    && !is_feed() 
    && !is_trackback()